# Snap text to a point

Tags: qt, qml

In my test application I am drawing triangles. In the down left corner of this triangle (lest call it nr 2) I need to add text that is just under the line. If the triangle rotates, the text should rotate as well. Heres an "explanation" image:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectMain
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "white"

        Item
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            rotation: 0

            property real trheight: 0;
            property real hfBase: 0;

            Canvas
            {
                id: canvas
                anchors.fill: parent

                // set properties with default values
                property real hFactor: 1    // height factor
                property real trbase: 200
                property color strokeColor: "black"
                property color fillColor: "yellow"
                property int lineWidth: 1
                property real alpha: 1
                property real parentWidth: parent.width; // try
                property real parentHeight: parent.height;

                onStrokeColorChanged: requestPaint();
                onFillColorChanged: requestPaint();
                onLineWidthChanged: requestPaint();

                onPaint:
                {
                    hFactor = Math.abs(hFactor)

                    var ctx = getContext("2d") // get context to draw with
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // remove what is painted so far
                    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
                    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor
                    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
                    ctx.globalAlpha = alpha

                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.translate(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight / 2);
                    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

                    // drawing part, first calculate height using Pythagoras equation
                    parent.trheight = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(trbase, 2) -
                            Math.pow(trbase / 2, 2))) * hFactor;

                    parent.hfBase = trbase * hFactor;
                    ctx.lineTo(parent.hfBase / -2, parent.trheight); // left arm
                    ctx.lineTo(parent.hfBase / 2, parent.trheight); // right arm

                    ctx.closePath(); // base drawn automatically
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }

            DropShadow
            {
                anchors.fill: canvas
                horizontalOffset: 0
                verticalOffset: 3
                radius: 3
                samples: 7
                color: "#80000000"
                source: canvas
            }
        }

        Text
        {
            //x: ?
            //y: ?

            font.family: "RobotoCondensed-Regular";
            font.pointSize: 12;
            text: qsTr("TEST");
            opacity: 0.6;
        }
    }
}
```

So ideally the end effect would look like this (edited in paint):

[image]

Then on 30 degree rotation like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to have the `Text` as a child item of the item that is rotated. Then you could just position it at the bottom of it and it would rotate with its parent.

However, your canvas covers the whole window, so your only option (given the current code) is to draw the text when you draw the shape. You can draw text with [`text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#text-method()), [`fillText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#fillText-method) or [`strokeText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#strokeText-method).

I would suggest rewriting your code to use the first approach I mentioned. Give each shape its own canvas, and make the text a child of the `Canvas` item (or its parent if you don't want the drop shadow effect to be applied to the text). Rotating an item is much cheaper than rotating by repainting a `Canvas`.